# Extract values from dates and concat them

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains date in format `YYYYMMDD` like `20230120`. I need to build string that contains: **current date** + **year from block_date** + **month from block_date** with `-` delimeter :

```
SELECT
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD.MM.YY'), '_', EXTRACT (year from to_date(block_date::text, 'yyyymmdd')), '_', EXTRACT (month from to_date(block_date::text, 'yyyymmdd')))
from test
```

It returns:
`20.01.23_2023_1` but I expect `20.01.23_2023_01`

I have 2 questions:

1. For `month from block_date` i expect 2 digits, like 01, 02, 11...
2. Can I simpify my select?

Comment: What data type is `block_date`? Why do you cast it to `text` and then back to a `date`?

Comment: block_date is integer

Comment: You should really fix that and convert it into a proper `date` column.

Comment: I know, but I can't. It's a legacy. I didn't design that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_char()` on the converted date as well:

```
CONCAT(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD.MM.YY'), '_', to_char(to_date(block_date::text, 'yyyymmdd'), 'yyyy_mm'))
```